# Cucumber Js callback issue? or feature issue?

Tags: javascript, callback, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'd like to write a feature like this:

```
Scenario: new Singleton create
  When a new, unmatchable identity is received
  Then a new tin record should be created
   And a new bronze record should be created
   And a new gold record should be created
```

which would tie to steps like this:

```
defineSupportCode(function ({ Before, Given, Then, When }) {

  var expect = require('chai').expect;
  var chanceGenerator = require('./helpers/chanceGenerator')
  var request = require('./helpers/requestGenerator')

  let identMap;

  // reset identMap before each scenario 
  Before(function () {
    identMap = [];
  });

  // should generate a valid identity
  // persist it in a local variable so it can be tested in later steps
  // and persist to the db via public endpoint
  When('a new, unmatchable identity is received', function (callback) {
    identMap.push(chanceGenerator.identity());
    request.pubPostIdentity(identMap[identMap.length-1], callback);
  });

  // use the local variable to retrieve Tin that was persisted
  // validate the tin persisted all the props that it should have
  Then('a new tin record should be created', function (callback) {
    request.pubGetIdentity(identMap[identMap.length-1], callback);

    // var self = this;

    // request.pubGetIdentity(identMap[identMap.length-1], callback, () => {
    //   console.log('never gets here...');
    //   self.callback();
    //   callback();
    // });

    // request.pubGetIdentity(identMap[identMap.length-1], (callback) => {
    //   console.log('never gets here...');
    //   self.callback();
    //   callback();
    // });

  });
```

The issue that I'm having is that I can't do anything in the Then callback.  That is where I'd like to be able to verify the response has the right data.

Here are relevant excerpts from the helper files:

```
var pubPostIdentity = function (ident, callback) {
  console.log('pubIdentity');
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://cucumber.utu.ai:4020/identity/' + ident.platform + '/' + ident.platformId,
    headers: {
      'X-Consumer-Custom-Id': ident.botId + '_' + ident.botId
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(ident)
  };
  console.log('ident: ', ident);
  request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('pubPostIdentity: ', err);
      callback(err);
    }
    console.log('pubPostIdentity: ', response.statusCode);
    callback();
  });
}

// accept an identity and retrieve from staging via identity public endpoint
var pubGetIdentity = function (ident, callback) {
  console.log('pubGetIdentity');
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://cucumber.utu.ai:4020/identity/' + ident.platform + '/' + ident.platformId,
    headers: {
      'X-Consumer-Custom-Id': ident.botId + '_' + ident.botId
    }
  };
  request(options, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('pubGetIdentity: ', err);
      callback(err);
    }
    console.log('pubGetIdentity: ', response.body);
    callback();
  });
}
```

Something that we are considering as an option is to re-write the feature to fit a different step definition structure.  If we re-wrote the feature like this:

```
Scenario: new Singleton create
    When a new, unmatchable 'TIN_RECORD' is received
    Then the Identity Record should be created successfully
    When the Identity Record is retreived for 'tin'
    Then a new 'tin' should be created
    When the Identity Record is retreived for 'bronze'
    Then a new 'bronze' should be created
    When the Identity Record is retreived for 'gold'
    Then a new 'gold' should be created
```

I believe it bypasses the instep callback issue we are wrestling with, but I really hate the breakdown of the feature.  It makes the feature less readable and comprehensible to the business.

So... my question, the summary feature presented first, is it written wrong?  Am I trying to get step definitions to do something that they shouldn't?  Or is my lack of Js skills shining bright, and this should be very doable, I'm just screwing up the callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd say your rewritten feature is wrong. You should never go back in the progression Given, When, Then. You are going back from the Then to the When, which is wrong.

Given is used for setting up preconditions. When is used for the actual test. Then is used for the assertions. Each scenario should be a single test, so should have very few When clauses. If you want, you can use Scenario Outlines to mix several very similar tests together.

In this case, is recommend to take it back to first principles and see if that works. Then build up slowly to get out working.

I suspect in this case that the problem is in some exception being thrown that isn't handled. You could try rewriting it to use promises instead, which will then be rejected on error. That gives better error reporting.

Comment: Graham thanks for the reply!  I've wrestling w/ a few thoughts:  First, should the When always / only be the Request statement?  And the Then handles evaluating the feedback from that When / request?  If this were the case, then the scenario we are trying to test would follow the WhenThenWhenThen... pattern (which I hate).  What I wanted this to do, was have a Then that blocks and makes multiple Rest requests to validate the data generated in the When.  Is that kosher?  Can I have a blocking Then that makes multiple external request calls?  Really appreciate the feedback!